# JAXB 2 - Changes in between Java EE 5 and Java EE 6

Tags: java, jaxb, version, jaxb2

I noticed a (kinda radical) change between the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html) and [Java EE 5 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/index.html) in what JAXB is concerned, in the sense that in the 6 tutorial the details are slim and there is no longer a chapter dedicated to JAXB as was the case in version 5.

What are the changes in JAXB from Java 5 to 6? Is the JAXB tutorial for EE 5 enough for EE 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java EE 5 included JAXB 2.0, and Java EE 6 includes JAXB 2.2.  Everything you could do in JAXB 2.0 you can still do in JAXB 2.2.

The main focus area for the [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) maintenance releases was to address some integration issues between JAXB and JAX-WS.  Below are some of the additions made to the public API:

- Introduction of `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation - When a class is being processed this annotation indicates that other classes should be processed as well.  This is commonly used to point to the sublasses of a domain class.
- Support for `@XmlTransient` at the type level  Specifying `@XmlTransient` at the type level allows a class to be removed from the mapping of an inheritance hierarchy (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html).

**Java EE 5 Components**

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee5-jsp-135162.html

**Java EE 6 Components**

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html